# Allow users to download file from S3 - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, download

I have PDF's stored on S3. Uploading them with Carrierwave works great. But how do I allow users to simple click a link to allow them to download the stored file onto their local machine? Here is my current attempt that is not working.

## Controller:

```
def download
    article = Article.find_by(id: params[:id])

    data = open("#{article.file}")
    send_data data, filename: "#{article.file}"
end
```

## View:

```
<td><%= link_to "Download File", download_article_path(article) %></td>
```

This isn't giving an error but it's also not download the file onto my machine. Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Try adding: type: "application/pdf", disposition: 'inline' to your download action. Also check out the docs for send_data: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data (in case you want to download The pdf as attachment instead of inline use: disposition attachment)

Comment: any news on this? I was trying to allow download an mp3 file but suddenly audio_tag updated a download button. I'm also interested in the solution for future stuff.